# Sending HTTP requests from Docker container to outter APIs?

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a working NodeJS application running inside Docker container. It needs access to some external vendor APIs. When I launch my app locally without Docker, it works like a charm sending HTTP requests here and there, but it doesn't work inside Docker. What kind of configuration do I need to provide to make it work? Couldn't find any viable answers for that.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.9.3-alpine

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app/

RUN apk add --no-cache make gcc g++ python

COPY src /app/src
COPY package.json /app
COPY package-lock.json /app
COPY tsconfig.json /app
COPY ormconfig.json /app

RUN npm install --production \
    && apk del make gcc g++ python \
    && npm run build:prod

RUN rm -rf /app/src && rm -f /app/package-lock.json \
  && rm -f /app/package.json \
  && rm -f /app/.npmrc \
  && rm -f /app/tsconfig.json \
  && mv /app/dist/*  /app && rm -rf /app/dist

EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: What error are you having? Docker is nothing special regarding outgoing http requests

Comment: @whites11The weird thing I found out after some testing is that the only thing that does not actually work is nodemailer. The thing is I tried to send emails before executing a specific action and I wrapped nodemailer `send` function into a Promise and the ridiculous part of it is that it neither goes to resolve, nor to reject, thus not completing the request. And this only happens in Docker, while successfully working in PM2 or whatever. I need to investigate the nodemailer APIs as this problem is quite confusing. :(